# Parsing JSON as Java Object is giving me some null values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to convert a JSON object into a POJO class,
but some values are ending up with null values while
others are set to the value from the JSON.
The response is

```
{
"intention_id": 12936,
"intention_datetime": "2021-03-09T09:58:16-03:00",
"status": "created",
"cuit": "20-314559999-9",
"branch": "Avellaneda 13",
"checkout": "8",
"terminal_number": "87980012",
"intention_type": "payment",
"original_amount": 1200.0,
"currency": "ARS",
"payment_methods_data": [
    {
        "payment_method_id": 1,
        "establishment_id": "29880765",
        "trace_number": 1090,
        "ticket_number": 131,
        "installments": [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "total_amount": 1200.0,
                "amount_per_installment": 200.0,
                "cft": 12.56,
                "tna": 14.87
            },
            {
                "bank_id": 28,
                "quantity": 6,
                "total_amount": 1200.0,
                "amount_per_installment": 200.0,
                "cft": 12.56,
                "tna": 14.87
            },
            {
                "quantity": 6,
                "total_amount": 1400.0,
                "amount_per_installment": 233.33,
                "cft": 12.56,
                "tna": 14.87
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "payment_method_id": 15,
        "establishment_id": "69880548",
        "trace_number": 2034,
        "ticket_number": 673,
        "installments": [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "total_amount": 1200.0,
                "amount_per_installment": 200.0,
                "cft": 12.56,
                "tna": 14.87
            },
            {
                "bank_id": 28,
                "quantity": 6,
                "total_amount": 1200.0,
                "amount_per_installment": 200.0,
                "cft": 12.56,
                "tna": 14.87
            },
            {
                "quantity": 6,
                "total_amount": 1400.0,
                "amount_per_installment": 233.33,
                "cft": 12.56,
                "tna": 14.87
            }
        ]
    }
],
"integrator_intention_id": "587cba61-ff27-46c6-ba8b-fd936665c35f",
"integrator": "alsea"
}
```

I'm ignoring the array elements,
so my Object Class is

```java
    public class ObjectResponseBimo {
    
    public int intention_id;    
    public String intention_datetime;   
    public String status;   
    public String cuit;
    public String branch;   
    public String checkout; 
    public String terminal_number;  
    public String intention_type;   
    public double original_amount;  
    public String currency; 
    public String integrator_intention_id;  
    public String integrator;

    public int getIntention_id() {
        return intention_id;
    }
    @JsonProperty("intention_id")
    public void setIntention_id(int intention_id) {
        this.intention_id = intention_id;
    }
    public String getIntention_datetime() {
        return intention_datetime;
    }
    @JsonProperty("intention_datetime")
    public void setIntention_datetime(String intention_datetime) {
        this.intention_datetime = intention_datetime;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    @JsonProperty("status")
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public String getCuit() {
        return cuit;
    }
    @JsonProperty("cuit")
    public void setCuit(String cuit) {
        this.cuit = cuit;
    }
    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }
    @JsonProperty("branch")
    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }
    public String getCheckout() {
        return checkout;
    }
    @JsonProperty("checkout")
    public void setCheckout(String checkout) {
        this.checkout = checkout;
    }
    public String getTerminal_number() {
        return terminal_number;
    }
    @JsonProperty("terminal_number")
    public void setTerminal_number(String terminal_number) {
        this.terminal_number = terminal_number;
    }
    public String getIntention_type() {
        return intention_type;
    }
    @JsonProperty("intention_type")
    public void setIntention_type(String intention_type) {
        this.intention_type = intention_type;
    }
    public double getOriginal_amount() {
        return original_amount;
    }
    @JsonProperty("original_amount")
    public void setOriginal_amount(double original_amount) {
        this.original_amount = original_amount;
    }
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    @JsonProperty("currency")
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public String getIntegrator_intention_id() {
        return integrator_intention_id;
    }
    @JsonProperty("integrator_intention_id")
    public void setIntegrator_intention_id(String integrator_intention_id) {
        this.integrator_intention_id = integrator_intention_id;
    }
    public String getIntegrator() {
        return integrator;
    }
    @JsonProperty("integrator")
    public void setIntegrator(String integrator) {
        this.integrator = integrator;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ObjectResponseBimo [intention_id=" + intention_id + ", intention_datetime=" + intention_datetime
                + ", status=" + status + ", cuit=" + cuit + ", branch=" + branch + ", checkout=" + checkout
                + ", terminal_number=" + terminal_number + ", intention_type=" + intention_type + ", original_amount="
                + original_amount + ", currency=" + currency + ", integrator_intention_id=" + integrator_intention_id
                + ", integrator=" + integrator + "]";
    }}
```

All the other getter and setter,
everyone has JsonProperty in the set method

I'm working with Jackson,
so I'm sending the object with

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
ObjectResponseBimo o = objectMapper.readValue(jsonToPost, ObjectResponseBimo.class);
return objectMapper.toString() + "\n" + o.toString();
```

The output is:

> ObjectResponseBimo [intention_id=0, intention_datetime=null,
> status=null, cuit=20-314559999-9, branch=Avellaneda 13, checkout=8,
> terminal_number=87980012, intention_type=payment,
> original_amount=1200.0, currency=ARS,
> integrator_intention_id=587cba61-ff27-46c6-ba8b-fd936665c35f,
> integrator=null ]

Comment: Could you please post the complete entity class ObjecrResponseBimo. Also try using the getters to get the individual property values and check the toString method.

Comment: @Ironluca I've edited the post

Comment: The problem that you are experiencing is not caused by any of the code that you included.  I took your code and your example JSON and it parses correctly.

Comment: @ClaudioScabbiaSepúlveda, With 2.7, it parses fine as DwB mentioned. Which version of Jackson are you using? JsonAutoDetect is an annotation in 2.x,  Are you using 1.x?

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided works fine. I have just copied it to the clean project and tested it.

I would give you couple of notes, not related to the question.

- Class variables should be `private`, and for Jackson no need to have setters and getters to make json. It used reflection.
- Class variables should be `CamelCase`. This is general practice in Java.

This is is, how your data class should look like:

```java
public class ObjectResponseBimo {

    @JsonProperty("intention_id")
    private int intentionId;
    @JsonProperty("intention_datetime")
    private String intentionDatetime;
    private String status;
    private String cuit;
    private String branch;
    private String checkout;
    @JsonProperty("terminal_number")
    private String terminalNumber;
    @JsonProperty("intention_type")
    private String intentionType;
    @JsonProperty("original_amount")
    private double originalAmount;
    private String currency;
    @JsonProperty("integrator_intention_id")
    private String integratorIntentionId;
    private String integrator;
}
```

And to work with json, you could use a tool to hide all routinse. E.g. [JacksonUtils](https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/JacksonUtils):

```java
ObjectResponseBimo obj = JacksonUtils.readValue(json, ObjectResponseBimo.class);
```

**P.S.** *Repeat, code that you have provided works fine on the clean project. Probably you have a problem someqhere else, and this is only the **side effect***.

Answer (score 0):

So I just tried to copy your code and made couple of changes.

1. Add below annotation at the top of your pojo class (ObjectResponseBimo.java)

```
  **@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)**
public class ObjectResponseBimo {
```

This will ignore the unknown properties from json having no match with equivalent java properties.

2. And for the object mapper, below snippet should be enough to get it work:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectResponseBimo ob = objectMapper.readValue(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("ObjectResponseBimo.json"), ObjectResponseBimo.class);
System.out.println(ob.toString());
System.out.println(ob.getIntention_id() + " | " + ob.getBranch());
```

I am not sure why toString() is not working for you. It is working for me though.